# Extra filtering on post query

Tags: wp-query

I have a membership system and want to restrict some posts depending on what level of membership they have. We have some voucher codes which bronze members are elegible for, some voucher codes for silver members, and some for gold. There are other restrictions I need to apply such as postcode vicinity and other conditions, but if I can sort the simple bronze, silver, gold I can apply any checks I need.

For viewing the post if somebody has a link, I can check this using a template_redirect filter. If the logged in member does not have the correct membership, I can show a no access page.

Is there a filter or a hook I can use to prevent posts showing on archive pages if their membership does not cover it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to manage access at the various places people might be able to see the posts, it's probably safest to create custom user roles. For example, WP autogenerates RSS feeds, so if you're only covering the single-post and archive views, you may not be covering the feeds themselves.

If you create custom roles, you can also create custom post types. In your case, you would create `bronze_member`, `silver_member`, and `gold_member` roles. You can then create `bronze_post`, `silver_post`, and `gold_post` custom post types with rewrites so they can all appear at whatever URLs you wish. You'd need to build a custom archive template that would query all of the post types, and that way, all posts can appear together, but those who are logged in with - say - silver status will only see the bronze and silver posts, not the gold posts.

See the WP Developer References for [user roles](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/) and [custom post types](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/).